# Where in the file system does cron launch a command

Tags: cron

When cron launches a command under my user ID, where in the file system does it actually launch it?

Let's say I have this python script:

```
import sys

filepath = sys.argv[1]
try:
    fp= open(filepath)
    ... stuff ...
except:
    print ("File not found.")
```

And I call the script in my crontab:

```
0 2 * * /home/me/scripts/bla.py filename
```

The file "filename" lives in /home/me/scripts. This gives me the 'File not found' message. So obviously my script got launched in some other place than /home/me/scripts. But where? I can put absolute paths into the crontab, but that's lots of clutter when multiple arguments are given. What's the best trick?

Comment: Maybe this cron job is running by `root` user and `root` does not have permissions to your homedir?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what system you're using, but on every system I've ever used `cron` launches jobs with their current working directory set to the user's home directory.  Some systems will document that behaviour in their man pages for `cron` or `crontab`, but if they don't (or if you want to be certain) then it's easy to check the situation for your system.  Just add this into your crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/pwd > $HOME/cron-pwd.txt
```

and wait for a minute or so for the `cron-pwd.txt` file to appear in your home directory.  And, obviously, remove that line from your `crontab` after you've read the file.

This means that your crontab command line can use pathnames relative to your home directory:

```
0 2 * * * scripts/bla.py scripts/filename
```

or you can build absolute paths by using the `$HOME` environment variable:

```
0 2 * * * $HOME/scripts/bla.py $HOME/scripts/filename
```

Alternatively, if writing out paths repeatedly isn't convenient then you can have your job change its own working directory before it starts running the program that will do the real work:

```
0 2 * * * cd $HOME/scripts ; ./bla.py filename
```

Some implementations of `cron` have enhancements that can affect the initial working directory, such as letting you specify a `HOME` environment variable that is different from your actual home directory.  I don't recommend using that feature to get your job launched in a specific directory unless you're very sure of what you're doing, because setting a non-standard `$HOME` can have unexpected side effects on commands that get executed as part of the job.

BTW, your question has only `0 2 * *` at the start of the crontab line, missing a field.  I assume that's just a copy-paste error.  Also, it doesn't invoke Python to run the script.  I assume that's also either a copy-paste error or your real script has a `#!` line that invokes your Python interpreter.